Unknown command: 'collectstatic' after overriding StaticFIlesConfig
I followed the instructions on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#s-customizing-the-ignored-pattern-list to override the ignore_patterns in my static files. Here are my steps on Django 5.0.6:

Created a new app app_staticfiles.
in app_staticfiles/apps.py, this code:

from django.contrib.staticfiles.apps import StaticFilesConfig


class AppStaticfilesConfig(StaticFilesConfig):
    name = 'app_staticfiles'
    ignore_patterns = ["CVS", ".*", "*~", "*.map",
                       "*.min.css", "*.min.js", "*.scss"]

In original staticfiles, there is the management directory that has the following commands collectstatic and findstatic.

Django project settings.py modified:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app_staticfiles',
]

Now when I run collectstatic, I get error Unknown command. Obviously since I have commented out the original app from Django. Is there a way for this to run as-is without having to copy the management commands from original place to the overwriting app?

I think the simplest way would be to just re-export the original staticfiles command(s) from your custom app:
app_staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.collectstatic import Command

__all__ = ["Command"]


I added the wrappers as you mentioned. Now I get this error:
  File "...\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 103, in set_options     ignore_patterns += apps.get_app_config("staticfiles").ignore_patterns                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "...\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 165, in get_app_config     raise LookupError(message) LookupError: No installed app with label 'staticfiles'.
Tried changing name = 'staticfiles' in the apps.py, still no joy.

Because of hardcoded app name apps.get_app_config("staticfiles").ignore_patterns in the collectstatic command, I had to rename my new app to staticfiles, and the config class name also to StaticFilesConfig (instead of app_staticfiles and AppStaticFilesConfig resp). It worked after that. I will post my final solution separately. Thanks @AKX.

Glad I could help in a roundabout way :)

To persistently customizeignore_patterns in the collectstatic command (provided by django.contrib.staticfiles) in Django 5.0.6, over and above instructions here, I had to do the following:

py manage.py startapp staticfiles. The name of this app must be staticfiles as when we link to the original collectstatic command later, it expects that name.
Clear apps.py and paste the following:

from django.contrib.staticfiles.apps import StaticFilesConfig


class StaticFilesConfig(StaticFilesConfig):
    name = 'staticfiles'
    ignore_patterns = ["CVS", ".*", "*~", "*.map", "*.min.css", "*.min.js",
                       "*.scss"]  # your custom patterns


You can delete admin.py, models.py, tests.py, views.py if you wish.
Make directory management/commands in this new app, and create empty files named exactly the same as files in django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands. As of Django 5.0.6, they are __init__.py, collectstatic.py, findstatic.py and runserver.py.
Add following code in each file:

# __init__.py
# Leave empty

# collectstatic.py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.collectstatic import Command

# findstatic.py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.findstatic import Command

# runserver.py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver import Command


In the Django project settings.py, replace django.contrib.staticfiles with your custome one:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'staticfiles',
]


Now when you type py manage.py help, you should see that the commands are available. Run these commands and you are done.

The problem with this approach is that if new commands are available, you will need to manually add the 1-line files. Also, what happens to the other files in the contrib app remains to be seen. If I face any issues, will report it back. I really wish there as a better way to customize this, there's too much of hard-coding.
